# no orientation notification when translucent set

Tags: android, themes, screen-orientation

Using phones that have `android 2.1 & 2.2` installed, using the simplest case of a hello world app and add  **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"** to the activity in the android manifest to have the app be transparent, the app sticks as portrait only and won't rotate to landscape when the phone is rotated.

Take the line out and the app rotates ok.  This is verified by adding the `override of onConfigurationChanged` and putting a breakpoint in that routine.  Brk hits when translucent isn't applied, doesn't when you add translucency.

However, using a **samsung galaxy tab using andr 2.2**, rotation works ok even with translucent applied.  Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: I cannot rotate a dialog activity with translucent theme when it is on top of an activity with configChanges set to orientation|keyboardHidden in the manifest file.

Comment: @col3-23 did you manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 5):

I had a same problem. Just add android:screenOrientation="sensor" in the manifest file after you specify theme:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:screenOrientation="sensor">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

So far I tested it on android 2.2 and 4.1 - works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this actually solved my problem. Any ideas why is this required? With other themes It is not

Answer (score 1):

I have a same problem... but in my case I used Translucent because I solve redrawn warning  (this warning appear when set color on android:background)

I solved the warning creating a Theme with parent Theme.Lignt and rewrite two attributes

Something like this

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/my_background</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/my_background</item>        
</style>
```

If you need use Translucent in ApiDemos has a sample when an activity have a translucent theme and orientation service works well