# Android land-layout doesn't work on real device

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm having a problem with the layout orientation.
I've recently made a android app that has a `layout` and `layout-land` but the problem is 
that when I test it on the emulator the screen orientation works, but when I install the 
apk into a real android device, the layout-land xml doesn't work even I tilt the device.

I've made  2 layout folder for `layout-land` and `layout` and set up the xml file with the same
name into it, and it works fine with the emulator but not in real device . I've checked the android device I tested and their is no problem with the settings. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Show your manifest file.

Comment: Maybe you forgot to turn on screen orientation on the device.

Comment: android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" use this in your activity declration in manifest. Hope!!! it work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid Names for Tablet :

```
layout-sw600dp-land
layout-sw720dp-land
```

Check your manifest you must add : `android:configChanges="orientation"` .. to your activities

with `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

you must add `android:screenOrientation="sensor"`

Comment: @BobMalooga i don t know if he use tablet or phone device :)

Comment: `layout-land` applies to all Android devices, not just tablets.

Comment: Yes. But the -swxyzdp- naming is for tablets

Comment: @ChuongPham You'r right but he is talking about `layout-sw600dp-land` not for `layout-land`

Comment: Bob & PiYusH: That's my point. The answer does not answer the OP's question as the OP has not specified tablets in his question. Please read the question again.

Comment: I realized that when I use (android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar") in the manifest to make the background activity transperent, then the layout-land doesn't work. Any way to solve this problem?

Comment: @user3264924 you must add this android:screenOrientation="sensor" 
Ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911830/no-orientation-notification-when-translucent-set

Comment: @user3264924: Maybe you need to read this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen) to get a full understanding of `android:screenOrientation` directive, and other directives. Else, you'll get into a lot of problems in the future when developing for Android.